# Wavefront sensor specifications Shack-Hartmann

Tags: optics, waves, geometric-optics, sensor

Why is the dynamic range of Shack-Hartmann wave-front sensors (As seen in the first image below) quoted in wavelengths and not in angles? I thought that one of the most important aspects of the wavefront sensor was its maximum "slope" which should be measured in radians or degrees (see second and third image).

How would you convert the "slope" dynamic range to the "Wavelengths" dynamic range quoted in all of the shack-hartmann sensor specifications. Is there a formula? Or have I misinterpreted what dynamic range means in this instance?

[image: Shack-Hartmann Specifications]

[image: Slope]

[image: equation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamic range quoted is the peak to peak range of the whole sensor, not an individual lenslet. The formulas are relating to the individual lenslets. For an individual lenslet WFS10-5C, the max angle is about $\frac{142 \mu m /2}{3.7mm} =0.019 rad\approx 1^\circ$. The maximum $\Delta Z= d \tan 1=2.7 \mu m$ or about $5.4 \lambda$ for $\lambda=0.5 \mu m$. Multiply that by the number of lenslets in one direction and you get total dynamic range. In adaptive optics I would normally think in terms of wavelengths rather than angle since I am not normally measuring purely slope although the maximum slope per lenslet is an important consideration.

The total dynamic range seems rather an optimistic number as well. It assumes that the only aberration is from a global wavefront tilt or slope. If you have $100 \lambda$ of spherical aberration some of the local slopes will be greater than the maximum angle that an individual lenslet can cope with.

Comment: Having designed and built a variety of Harmann sensors, I agree that those specs probably cannot be met for arbitrary wavefronts.  It's more likely that the "100 $\lambda$ " assumes a much smaller error from one sub-aperture to the next.  BTW, I think you should change "number of pixels" to "number of subapertures[or wavelets]", as there are certainly many pixels in the camera for each hartmann spot.

Comment: So in the example from DocPhil, if my lenslet array had 40 X 40 lenslets, i could do 1600*5.4λ=8640λ that seems far too high. Is it  just in one direction say 40 lenslets, 40*5.4λ= 216λ. So slope is quoted in wavelengths across the whole of shack hartmann aperture.

Comment: Yes,  I should have said in one direction

Answer (score 0):

[image]By using this formula I am not able to calculate the dynamic range in terms of \lambda. For the attached table specification of WFS (73 x 45), the dynamic range is greater than 500\lambda. Here the lenslet pitch is 150micrometer and the focal length is 4.1 mm.

Here are the details

1. Lenslet pitch= 150 micrometer and effective focal length = 4.1 mm (MLA150-5C)
2. Lenslet pitch= 150 micrometer and effective focal length = 5.2 mm (MLA150-7AR)
3. Lenslet pitch= 3000 micrometer and effective focal length = 14.6 mm (MLA300-14AR)